# Why is my NavBar disabled I can't click buttons or search

Tags: reactjs, navbar, disable

I have this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-working-navbar-ubw67?file=/src/components/elements/NavBar.jsx)

And suddenly I cant click on the Components and I cant remember what I did to deserve this :)

Please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `div` element that you defined inline with your Navbar Form: [image].  As you can see from the developer tools, this div is being created the same size and position as your nav, but it's over top of your nav, so no click events make their way to the nav itself.

Removing the div fixes it.